# Is it me or IPv6 is still a niche thing?

Tags: networking, ipv6

Some hosting providers don’t support IPv6 at all, others such as DigitalOcean only support IPv6 on non-custom Droplets and don’t support it at all for load balancers and other shenanigans.

I’ve read that IPv6 requires ICMP to work properly, but can’t find good documentation on what to allow in iptables.

So, what’s the deal here... my quest to adopt IPv6 has been very frustrating so far. Am I missing something?

Should I just drop the project?

Comment: Regarding ICMP, don't filter, just rate limit. If you must, see rfc4890.

Answer (score 1):

Still a niche thing. It is not only ISP's - it is a lot of routing equipment either that does not (or not fully) support IPV6.

Btw., IPV4 ALSO requires ICMP to work properly. Properly i.e. to have optimal fragmentation size - without there are defaults that are quite often workable, but it is not "properly".

I am using IPV6 as secondary network in parts (because I run no risk of private IP overlap) but both ISP's and enterprise level customers are mostly duefully unaware of it, and / or not bothering with it. Part of a chicken/egg problem - as company, you inteact with the internet and all kinds of software and as long as you can not switch to totally to IPv6 - why bother to switch at all?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As a privacy researcher, the reason I am worried about IPv6 is that apparently, devices can leak IPv6 traffic outside of VPNs... I self-host my own strongSwan VPN and, at least in Firefox, I am not leaking IPv6 traffic even though my server is not IPv6 enabled. Do you have advice in this regard?

Comment: I'd disagree on the "niche" characterization. I'll admit cloud providers are still playing catch-up, but all the major network equipment manufacturers support it. All the major ISPs support it as do the larger web sites.

Comment: The problem is that this still is a niche - the niche of either you controlling your infrastructure, and / or you not interacting with anyone on IPv4. For enterprises that niche breaks apart with a lot of equipment and software. It should not, but it does. The moment you do i.e. IP phones and your phone provider does not support it (but wants to) - what you do? Thank heaven most software is getting there, but getting there is not being there. For now, I would say - not usable in most cases. You can dual use, but you still will need IPv4 for a lot of scenarios.

Comment: I suppose that 30% adoption (and growing) could be called "niche" but it isn't the first word I would use.

Comment: @TomTom Would love to pick your brain for the privacy guides project (see https://www.youtube.com/sunknudsen). If you are down, please get in touch.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Would love to pick your brain for the privacy guides project (see https://www.youtube.com/sunknudsen). If you are down, please get in touch.

Comment: It depends quite a bit on where you live. Here only a few ISPs even support IPv6. If you look at countries like Sweden (5.6%) or Spain (2.6%), then yes, it is still a niche. In other counties, Germany, USA, India, it is much more present (over 40%)

Comment: THe ISP side does not really matter. The problem is then the next step down. Also "end user ISP's" are nice- but I doubt most end user routers support that ;) THIS is wher ethe problem comes up. It is a niche - even if your country has 40% penetratrion, it is YOUR country, not the world. So, if you want interaction - back to IPV4.